# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) when passing Model.where(...) collection to delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm trying to run a scheduled update for a model every hour but only if it was last update over 24 hours ago. The following works if I have only `@rentals = Rental.all`, but once I add .where(..) I get a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`:

```
def delayed_stat_updates
  @rentals = Rental.where("updated_at < ?", 24.hours.ago)
  StatsController.delay(queue: 'stats').stat_updates(@rentals)
  StatsController.delay(queue: 'stats').index_check(@rentals)
  StatsController.delay(queue: 'stats').update_stats_error_attribute(@rentals)
  StatsController.delay(queue: 'stats').error_notification_email
end
```

How can I resolve this? Also, is this a good way to run these updates? Previously I grabbed the objects inside each method but if one of the updates takes too long it could start grabbing extra objects for the next update by accident.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that, but have you tried just interpolating the 24.hours.ago in to the where clause string? Might be a valid solution, though it doesn't truly answer your question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. Maybe I'll just get `@time = Time.now - 24.hours` and pass that to each block, then I can use that to make sure I'm getting the same number of objects every time...

Comment: So you tried `Rental.where("updated_at < #{24.hours.ago}")` and still got an error? The problem must be elsewhere, because both that, and what you posted originally, are valid (at least, in Rails 3.1).

Comment: Yes, tried that - not sure where the problem is... (P.S. I'm using Rails 3.2)

Comment: include your full error message. the `Rental.where` clause you have should work just fine. I just did it in a rails 3.2.3 project.

Comment: I've just checked this code without delayed_job and it works. How can I do get the full error message when using delayed_job?

Comment: I have a hunch that serialising activerecord scopes doesn't really work (and delayed job needs to serialize the method arguments to store them in its table). Try tacking .all onto the end, ie `Rental.where(...).all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rental.where("updated_at < ?", 24.hours.ago)` is completely valid, i think that the problem can be caused by difference between Arel(.where) and Array(.all) objects. Just try    `Rental.where("updated_at < ?", 24.hours.ago).all`

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. Just doing `where` will not cause AR to actually go retrieve the data yet, but doing `all` will.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, by the way I wrote a comment before you answered this saying that delayed_job seems to be causing the problem. If I don't use delayed_job then I can drop the .all, now I see why :)